# jQuery validation on dynamic elements added with PHP

Tags: jquery, validation, dynamic

I'm trying to validate some check boxes that are dynamicly added to the page but im not having any luck with it.

As you can see, rule is that at-least one checkbox has to be selected.

Here is the code where i add check boxes to page:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
 echo utf8_decode("<input type='checkbox' class='ne_serijaliziraj' name='smjer{}' value='{$row[0]}'>{$row[1]}");
```

}

And this is my validation code:

```
$(function(){
  $('#submit_second').click(function(){
    $("#sp_drugi_korak").validate({
      rules: {
          "smjer{}": {
              required: true,
              minlength: 1
          }
       }
   });
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please state which library or plugin you are using for the validation.

Comment: jQuery Validation Plugin